# Some question regarding pwm of PIC microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pic, pwm

Hello guys i have some question regarding PWM.

[image]

What does it mean by pwm master-slave?? Why it is called master-slave??

Comment: where's that sentence from? Official documentation? app note? third party source? Please link to it, probably best answerable from context!

Comment: You can find this statement in several Microchip documents. One is [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/31014a.pdf) section 14.1 on page 2.

Comment: The master/slave in the PWM context actually means that the 16-bit register is split into two 8-bit register. One of them, the (slave), is used to hold the value to compare with the timer count register to select the timer count value where the PWM output is set low. The other, the (master), can be written at any time during the PWM period and its value is copied to the (slave) register when the PWM period restarts.